# how to fix orientation issues on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I wanted to ask about android orientation; 
I made 2 different folders for layout: layout and layout-land
when the orientation changes while the application is running i don't want to restart the running activity so i fixed that problem by adding the following line of the manifest file

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

the problem then is that the app is not switching to the appropriate layout when i rotate the phone

does someone have any idea about the best way to handle the orientation changes of an android application ( i want to keep the state of the layout when i switch )

Comment: what are the folders are your layouts for portrait and landscape in?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: yes, i stored my xml files in the files

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842691/handle-states-of-orientation-changes

Comment: i don't think i can use "onSaveInstanceState()" or "onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()" because i have a lot of items on each layout ==> i have to save them all ???

Comment: Have you considered using Fragments? Fragment instances can be [retained](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) across orientation changes but the views will be [recreated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29).

Comment: the problem is that i don't want them to be recreated :(

Answer (score 0):

**Simple: Let Android do the hard work.**

Saying configChanges="orientation" overrides the default orientation behavior especially if you're using multiple layout files.

Change this:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

To this

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"/>
```